# Is it necessary to add DEFAULT NULL in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database

If I create a new table and I have a field that I want to be NULL by Default, is it necessary to add DEFAULT NULL or by default is it already NULL?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is null by default -- no need to explicitly declare it.

Answer (score 1):

actually it is optional because by default it is `NULL`, example

```
CREATE TABLE hello
(
   ID INT NOT NULL,
   NAME VARCHAR(50),
   OTHERs VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT 'FISH')
)
```

`DEFAULT` is only used if you want other values except `NULL`. In the example above, when you try to insert `ID` only, the values for `NAME` and `OTHERs` are `NULL` and `FISH`, respectively.